Basic setup with Cloud SQL and IAM authentication
Let's say I have a database instance, two databases db1 and db2, and two users user1 and user2@PROJECT_ID.iam (BUILTIN and CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT). In other words:
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "test-sql" {
  deletion_protection = false
  name = "test-sql"
  region = "europe-central2"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_15"
  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    database_flags {
      name = "cloudsql.iam_authentication"
      value = "on"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_service_account" "test-sql2" {
  account_id = "user2"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "test-sql2-client" {
  project = "PROJECT_ID"
  role = "roles/cloudsql.client"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.test-sql2.email}"
  condition {
    title = "test-sql"
    expression = <<-EOT
      resource.name == 'projects/PROJECT_ID/instances/test-sql'
      && resource.service == 'sqladmin.googleapis.com'
    EOT
  }
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "test-sql2-instance-user" {
  project = "PROJECT_ID"
  role = "roles/cloudsql.instanceUser"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.test-sql2.email}"
  condition {
    title = "test-sql"
    expression = <<-EOT
      resource.name == 'projects/PROJECT_ID/instances/test-sql'
      && resource.service == 'sqladmin.googleapis.com'
    EOT
  }
}

$ gcloud sql databases create db1 \
  --instance test-sql --project PROJECT_ID
$ gcloud sql users create user1 \
  --instance test-sql --password 1 \
  --project PROJECT_ID

$ gcloud sql databases create db2 \
  --instance test-sql --project PROJECT_ID
$ gcloud sql users create user2@PROJECT_ID.iam \
  --type CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
  --instance test-sql \
  --project PROJECT_ID

And then I try to create a table:
$ psql -h proxy -U user1 db1 \
  -c "CREATE TABLE t (f VARCHAR)"
CREATE TABLE
$ psql -h proxy -U user2@PROJECT_ID.iam db2 \
  -c "CREATE TABLE t (f VARCHAR)"
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: create table t (f varchar)
                     ^
$ psql -h proxy -U postgres -c \\l
                                                                      List of databases
     Name      |       Owner       | Encoding | Locale Provider |  Collate   |   Ctype    | ICU Locale | ICU Rules |            Access privileges
---------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------
 cloudsqladmin | cloudsqladmin     | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |            |           |
 db1           | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |            |           |
 db2           | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |            |           |
 postgres      | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |            |           |
 template0     | cloudsqladmin     | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |            |           | =c/cloudsqladmin                       +
               |                   |          |                 |            |            |            |           | cloudsqladmin=CTc/cloudsqladmin
 template1     | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |            |           | =c/cloudsqlsuperuser                   +
               |                   |          |                 |            |            |            |           | cloudsqlsuperuser=CTc/cloudsqlsuperuser
(6 rows)
$ psql -h proxy -U postgres -c \\drg
                                    List of role grants
        Role name         |         Member of         |       Options       |    Grantor
--------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------------
 cloudsqlagent            | cloudsqlsuperuser         | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 cloudsqlimportexport     | cloudsqlsuperuser         | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 cloudsqllogical          | cloudsqlsuperuser         | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 cloudsqlobservability    | pg_monitor                | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 cloudsqlreplica          | pg_monitor                | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 cloudsqlsuperuser        | pg_checkpoint             | ADMIN, INHERIT, SET | cloudsqladmin
 cloudsqlsuperuser        | pg_monitor                | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 cloudsqlsuperuser        | pg_signal_backend         | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 postgres                 | cloudsqlsuperuser         | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqladmin
 user2@PROJECT_ID.iam     | cloudsqliamserviceaccount | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqlagent
 user1                    | cloudsqlsuperuser         | INHERIT, SET        | cloudsqlagent
(11 rows)

Okay, I was able to create a table under user1 because it's a member of cloudsqlsuperuser, and that is the owner of db1. user2@PROJECT_ID.iam is a member of cloudsqliamserviceaccount, and is not the owner of db2. Then I guess I should not use gcloud sql databases create with IAM authentication, and let user2@PROJECT_ID.iam create a database itself?
$ gcloud sql databases delete db2 \
  --instance test-sql --project PROJECT_ID
$ psql -h proxy -U postgres \
  -c 'ALTER ROLE "user2@PROJECT_ID.iam" CREATEDB'
ALTER ROLE
$ psql -h proxy -U user2@PROJECT_ID.iam postgres \
  -c "CREATE DATABASE db2"
$ psql -h proxy -U user2@PROJECT_ID.iam db2 \
  -c "CREATE TABLE t (f VARCHAR)"
CREATE TABLE

Is it really so that I should not use gcloud sql databases create with IAM authentication? This sounds strange. Maybe there's a more canonical way of doing things when you need one database, one user and IAM authentication?
